# Kotlin: How to filter elements from a list lower than the first element?

Tags: android, list, kotlin, functional-programming, android-ktx

I have a function chain going and I need to filter items from a Kotlin list that are lower than the first item.

For example, in [3, 5, 2, 7, 1, 0, 9] I want to be left with [3, 5, 7, 9]

I don't see a way to compare by a value in a functional chain since I don't have a saved reference to the list to get its indices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this with functional operators, but if you're opposed to pausing the chain to assign to a variable before continuing, you can use `run` or `let` to sort of keep the flow going:

```
list
    //...
    .run { filter { it < first() } }
    //...
```

Comment: DOH. You are so right. I can't believe I didn't even think of this! This is exactly what I wanted. <3